# SQLQuery to search based on criteria

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have a table say ActionRole:

```
 RoleId  ActionId
 31      1
 31      2
 31      3
 32      1
 32      4
 33      2
 33      4
 34      5
 34      6
```

I need all the RoleId from table where any of the mapped 
    ActionId corresponding to RoleId is not in list {1,3,7,11}

I need RoleId as:{33,34} as final answer

Select RoleId from ActionRole where ActionId not in(1,3,7,11)

This is what I tried. But it doesn't work as expected and I suspect 
   this is because:

Since RoleId 31 has ActionId '1' as well as '2'.So,for ActionId '2'
   ,ActionId is not in {1,3,7,11},so this RoleId also comes in my 
   result which I don't need.I need all the RoleIds which do not have 
   any associated  ActionId which are in the list provided

```
Select RoleId from ActionRole where ActionId not in(1,3,7,11)
```

I need RoleId as:{33,34} as final answer.These are the RoleIds which do not 
  contain any associated ActionId mentioned in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you have a separate `Roles` table.  If so, a more efficient version is:

```
select r.RoleId
from Roles r 
where not exists (select 1
                  from ActionRole ar
                  where ar.RoleId = r.RoleId and        
                        ar.ActionId in (1, 3, 7, 11)
                 );
```

I also strongly encourage you to *never* use `NOT IN` with a subquery.  It does not behave as you would expect if any returned values in the subquery are `NULL`.  `NOT EXISTS` behaves intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

use subquery

```
select distinct RoleId from ActionRole 
where RoleId not in  (
select RoleId from ActionRole where ActionId  in(1,3,7,11)
 )
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8db330f0f77674d96fd59cdfdf4b6a48)

```
RoleId
33
34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table (RoleId int , actionId int)

     insert into @t values (31,1)
     insert into @t values (31,2)
     insert into @t values (31,3)
     insert into @t values (32,1)
     insert into @t values (31,4)
     insert into @t values (33,2)
     insert into @t values (33,4)
     insert into @t values (34,5)
     insert into @t values (34,6)

     select * from @t t1
     where not exists ( select 1 from @t t where t1.RoleId=t.RoleId and actionId in (1,3,7,11))
```